# Why var_dump does not show null bytes?

Tags: php, null, var-dump

I had 2 cases where null bytes `\0` are being appended to my data.

1.Casting object to an array

```
class myClass {
    private $var;
    function __construct() {}   
}
$myObject = (array) new myClass();
var_dump(array_map("addslashes", array_keys($myObject)));
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "\0myClass\0var" }
```

2.When decrypting encrypted data:

```
function encrypt_data($data) {
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH , SALT , $data , MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}

function decrypt_data($data) {
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH , SALT , $data , MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}

$data = '12345678901234567 aasdasd';
$edata = encrypt_data($data);
var_dump(addslashes(decrypt_data($edata)));
```

Outputs:

```
string(39) "12345678901234567 aasdasd\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

But I would never notice `\0`s if not `addslashes` function. Why just `var_dump()` does not show those ? `var_dump("Hello\0 World");` for example outputs 'Hello World'. In my opinion bad representation of data. And as far as I know `\0` byte is end of char array (string in PHP) in C and PHP is implemented in C.

Comment: `var_dump("Hello\0 World");` _does_ show the character. It's your browser that doesn't make it clear. Try that code from command line, I get `string(12) "Hello\000 World"` as the output.

Comment: Dont see \0 on MAC `php -a; php > var_dump("Hello\0 World");
string(12) "Hello World"`

Comment: I'm on a mac as well.`php -a; php > var_dump("Hello\0 World");
string(12) "Hello\000 World"` Not sure why you're getting different results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var_dump` outputs strings as is. If your string contains a `NUL` byte, that `NUL` byte will be output as is. The problem is that a `NUL` byte typically doesn't show up as anything in the browser, or possibly even the command line.

An indication is that the displayed string length is different from what you see. A `string(42) "abc"` probably has quite a number of "hidden" characters in it. Obviously this gets harder and harder to eyeball the longer your string gets...

`var_export` makes `NUL` bytes and similar much more obvious.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Is there any combination of `var_export()` + `var_dump()` ?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you have a hunch that you may be dealing with hidden characters, you'll have to probe in more detail.